# selenium webdriver.Firefox not starting for non-sudo user

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I have a python method that sets up a browser in headless-mode on a linux server for website scraping with selenium.  The display gets setup perfectly fine regardless of which user executes the python script but if the `sudo` user doesn't execute the script it will hang at the `webdriver.Firefox()` setup line indefinitely.

Here is the full method:

```
def browserSetup(self, browser=None):
    try:
        # now Firefox will run in a virtual display. you will not see the browser.  
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        self.display.start()

        if self.verbose:
            print "Virtual display started for browser instantiation."

        #change user agent
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1")
        profile.set_preference("webdriver.log.file", "webdriver.log")

        # Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

        if self.verbose:
            print "Browser window object established @ %s." % browser

        return browser
    except Exception, e:
        raise e
```

So, to repeat my issue: ***if the script is not executed as `sudo` then the script will hang indefinitely at the `webdriver.Firefox` creation line.  Why would this be happening?***

***UPDATE: The problem is this line here:***

```
 browser = webdriver.Firefox() #with or without the profile variable - the results are the same
```

***UPDATE AGAIN***
Several people in the comments below have suggested I try running `Firefox` from the command line manually to see if there are any issues; here are the results:

```
#initialize the virtual display
$ sudo Xvfb :10 -extension RANDR
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!

#now start firefox in another ssh window (since the Xvfb process is consuming my prompt)
$ export DISPLAY=:10
$ firefox

(firefox:6347): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

The last error message displays hundreds of times...

Comment: What are the permissions on firefox. How about `sudo chmod 777 location/to/firefox` and then trying it. Just shooting in the dark :)

Comment: doing a `dpkg -L firefox` primarily shows all the firefox files in `/usr/lib/firefox` so I did a quick `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/firefox` and I am still having my issue.  So, no that did not fix my problem

Comment: Does this run as your normal user? Does the user where it's not working have permissions to start X?

Comment: Has this ever worked? or is this a new project?

Comment: @Oz123 it only runs as `sudo`, even my normal user cannot start it.

Comment: Any chance you're not running this within a virtualenv? Total shot in the dark.

Comment: Add `profile.set_preference("webdriver.log.file", "/some/file")` and see if that file (change the path to where your user has write permissions) contains any useful info.

Comment: @2rs2ts no, I'm running this within `Xvfb`

Comment: @André running firefox manually after starting `Xvfb` gives me an error: `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10".`

Comment: @André I just tried `sudo Xvfb :10 -extension RANDR` to no avail

Comment: @sadmicrowave did you try setting the log path in the profile as I said in a previous comment ? Maybe that log will get populated with some interesting info.

Comment: @André I added it (see my OP for the line) and after execution there is no `webdriver.log` file in the location specified.

Comment: for what it's worth I've also tried switching to chrome using the `webdriver.Chrom("/path/to/chromedriver")` syntax, and it still stopped in the same place

Comment: did you check perms on usr/lib?  If it's dir access, you can either run as a user that has access to that dir or move the drivers inside your program's folder structure.
    sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib

Comment: @sadmicrowave did you find a solution for this? Hope so because I am also running in to this issue.

Comment: It wasn't a very clean solution but I first used chrome and chromedriver instead of firefox; I think I had to add sudo access to the chromedriver file.  But ultimately I found a way to exclude Selenium and the virtual display & browser entirely by extending urllib(2).  No need to include another library if you don't need to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to start the **Xvfb** (virtual frame-buffer X server) in the background.

For example, `$ sudo Xvfb :1 &` or `$ sudo Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x1024x8`.

Then, whenever you want to run your script, do it with the DISPLAY environment variable set accordingly.

For example, `$ DISPLAY=:1 python your_script.py`.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess, but here's what I suspect.

`sudo` clears your environment variables when you start Firefox via it. That includes the `DISPLAY` variable as well.

Two ways to disable this behavior:
- Disable `env_reset` in your sudoers configuration.
- Use `sudo -i`, that will preserve the value of `DISPLAY`.

Comment: do you mean `sudo -E` for preserving environment variables?

Comment: That's also an option to preserve them.

Comment: This does not make a difference for my issue.  Executing my python script with the -E option does not help.  Not only that, my OP stated that I'm trying to run this script **without** using `sudo`

Comment: Oh I see, the OP was a bit misleading before the update.

Comment: Try checking out where firefox hangs. After you started xvfb and firefox, from another xterm: `DISPLAY=:1 import -window root screen.png` and check screen.png.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to open usr/lib up for good but try testing it with open perms on the directory.

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib
```

If that's the issue, you can always move the drivers inside your application.  Unless you're sharing them with many people, they're small enough to have several copies.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else like me that until today could be having this problem: 
For me was due to Firefox needs to be able to create a profile, which is created at the user home folder. The user i created didn't had its own user home folder so when i created it the problem was solved.